# Is there a maximum number of categories that can be returned in the Yelp API?

Tags: yelp

If I made an api call like the one below:

```
from yelpapi import YelpAPI

yelpApi = YelpAPI(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret)
searchResults = yelpApi.search_query(name = 'food', location='San Jose, CA')
```

Is there a maximum amount of responses that could be returned for the category section of the response for any given business (e.g. searchResults['businesses'][0]['categories'])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't a terribly authoritative source, a quick search turned up [this article](http://www.localvisibilitysystem.com/2013/07/19/yelp-business-categories-list/) featuring the claim that there are 698 possible categories (at the time of writing) and any individual business can be tagged with **up to three** at maximum.